# Printing double in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

I have method like that:

```
try 
{
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ..............................
    while (rs.next()) {               
        money = rs.getDouble("money");
        System.out.println(money);              
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

How can I properly print money value in double? Because when I print money i see something like this: 250.0 but in database i have value 250.00

Comment: What is the datatype of that column in DB?

Comment: Yes, but in that method

Comment: datatype is decimal(10,2)

Comment: Ah you want to read in the type/some metadata and print it accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double datatype formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937774/double-datatype-formatting)

Comment: Yes. I used that mehod in JPanel to print values from database

Comment: don't use double for currency, use rs.getBigDecimal(), you can then correctly set it's scale and use .toString() afterwards if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will possibly lose precision when working with `double`, which is bad when dealing with `currency`. Use `BigDecimal` instead

```
while (rs.next()) {               
   BigDecimal money = rs.getBigDecimal("money");
   //if needed set it's scale to something else
   //money=money.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //2 decimals rounded up
   System.out.println(money);             
}
```

Comment: Ok but look. In Jpanel I have something like this Class.setMoney(Double.valueOf(jTextField2.getText())); How can I get now convert value from JTextField to BigDecimal ?

Comment: @Adamo Class.setMoney(new BigDecimal(jTextField2.getText())); - constructor of BigDecimal can take string argument